# Android studio 2.2.2 does not showing cloud option in project structure

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I went to the Tool->Firebase and connect my android application to Firebase but I am writing the code in the `onCreate` method (`code -Firebase.setAndroidContex(this)`) it showing an error that cannot resolve this symbol.Please help.

Comment: `Firebase.setAndroidContex()` is a call from the Firebase 2.x SDK. It seems likely that you're using the latest Firebase SDKs, which don't require that call anymore. To learn how to integrate the latest Firebase into your Android project, see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an error of cannot resolve symbol then most probably there is a spelling mistake in this case I guess it is setAndroidContext(this) instead of setAndroidContex(this)

Comment: Kshitij - are you really "guessing"? Suggested edit is "If you are getting an error of cannot resolve symbol then most probably there is a spelling mistake. Given your description, you should use . `setAndroidContext(this)` instead of `setAndroidContex(this)`." And use the code tags in your answer - the proper formatting helps with readability for others.